# Laravel 8 JetStream Bootstrap 4

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, sass, local, laravel-jetstream

I am using the jetstream UI with Laravel 8 and I have checked an I am aware that the Laravel team has no plans to make a Bootstrap version of the UI but I'm only comfortable with bootstrap and can't use a CDN because I need to make changes to BS4.
Is it possible to install BS4 and SASS on a Laravel project without affecting the Laravel JetStream UI.

Answer (score 10):

Why border when you can use [Jetstrap](https://github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap)

Install Jetstream as usual, then install Jetstrap to enable you automatically replace Tailwind resources for Bootstrap. And if you use AdminLTE or CoreUi Jetstrap got you covered. Checkout the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 Jetstream 2 with Bootstrap 5 and Vue 3

```
php --version
node --version
npm --version
composer global require laravel/installer
laravel new blog
cd blog
php artisan --version
vim .env
vim app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
php artisan migrate

composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
npm install vue@next vue-loader@next --save-dev
npm install @vue/compiler-sfc --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
npm install bootstrap@latest bootstrap-icons @popperjs/core --save-dev
npm install resolve-url-loader@^4.0.0 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
npm install sass sass-loader jquery --save-dev
npm uninstall @tailwindcss/forms @tailwindcss/typography tailwindcss
npm uninstall alpinejs
mkdir resources/sass
> resources/sass/_variables.scss
vim resources/sass/_variables.scss
> resources/sass/app.scss
vim resources/sass/app.scss
vim resources/js/bootstrap.js
vim resources/js/app.js
vim webpack.mix.js
npm install
npm run dev
```

Edit all files (below) with Bootstrap 5 format

```
vim resources/views/welcome.blade.php
vim resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php
vim resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
vim resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php
vim resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
vim resources/views/dashboard.blade.php
vim resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
vim resources/views/auth/forgot-password.blade.php
vim resources/views/auth/reset-password.blade.php 
vim resources/views/auth/confirm-password.blade.php
vim resources/views/auth/verify-email.blade.php
```